# Unexpected result from ternary operator

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I am trying to understand how the ternary operator works in C++.

I expect to see the same output for both print statements, yet the second print statement outputs 49.

*Why is this?*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    cout << "First character " << '1' << endl;
    cout << "Second character " << (test ? 3 : '1') << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

First character 1
Second character 49

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'1' got converted to an integer which represented the ASCII code for '1'. The ternary operator is supposed to have two values of the same type.  You can not have 3 (an integer) and '1' (a char).  That's why the conversion took place.  If the implicit conversion could not have happened then a compiler error would have been generated.

Comment: More clearly: Every expression has a type at compile time: The type of `(test ? 3 : '1')` is the common type of the last two parts: `int` and `char`. And the common type of those is an `int`.  And (on this machine) `'1'` is represented by the value 49 in hardware.

Comment: This effect can have other nasty surprises. See http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/217

Comment: @alter igel Whoa, never new that about the ternary operator or cppquiz.org.  Thanks for both!

Comment: @shargors I just found out about it recently. I think it could be very useful to help settle arguments about what code does between developers.